# Getting magical error from flex when scanning EOF

Tags: compiler-construction, flex-lexer

my code looks like this

```
<CHR><<EOF>>    {
    ctx->message(cxx::errors::EOFINSTRCHR, ctx->line()); // error msg
    if(chr_len>0){
        return cxx::parser::make_INTLIT(casem::multichar_to_int(chr,chr_len),ctx->line()); //char value
    }
    return cxx::parser::make_EOF(ctx->line()); //stop scan
}
```

When I am reading a char and I encounter end of file I want:

1. Print error message
2. Print matched char (value of char)
3. End the scan

I have input like this:

`char x = 'a <<EOF>>` (note there is not closing ' )

And I am getting this output:

```
Error (line 19): End of file in string or character literal
19: integer literal 97
Error (line 19): End of file in string or character literal <-- what is this doing there ???
========== cxx done ==========
```

Thank you for any help !

EDIT:

```
<CHR><<EOF>>    {
    ctx->message(cecko::errors::EOFINSTRCHR, ctx->line());
    if(chr_len>0){
        BEGIN(INITIAL);
        return cecko::parser::make_INTLIT(casem::multichar_to_int(chr,chr_len),ctx->line());
    }
    return cecko::parser::make_EOF(ctx->line());
}
```

Adding BEGIN(INITIAL) fixed problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show how `chr_len` gets set or modified, but I imagine it has to do with what you see. If `chr_len` is not 0, that clause won't terminate the scan; instead, it returns an `INTLIT`. Then `yylex` will be called again; if `chr_len` has somehow been reset to 0, only then will EOF be sent (but only after again printing the error message).

It's not really a great idea to repeatedly call `yylex()` at the end of input. Under certain circumstances, it can create problems. It's best to arrange for EOF to be returned without entering the scan loop, perhaps using an `eof_reached` flag.